# Customize R Box-Plot

Tags: r, max, customization, min, boxplot

I would like to draw some Kind of Box-Plot, that shows the Median of my Data. In contrast to a regular Box-Plot I would like to expand the box to the Minimum and Maximum value of my data instead of the quartiles. 
Example:

```
x <- c(1,3,5,7,9)
```

A regular Boxplot of x would have the following stats:

- 1: lower Whisker
- 3: lower end of box
- 5: median
- 7: upper end of box
- 9: upper Whisker

I would like to get:

- 1: lower end of box
- 5: median
- 9: upper end of box

Anyone who can help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `ggplot` you can control those cutoffs explicitly by setting them in call.

```
ggplot() +
  geom_boxplot(
    aes(x = 1
        , lower = min(x)
        , middle = median(x)
        , upper = max(x)
        , ymin = min(x)
        , ymax = max(x))
    , stat = "identity"
  )
```

[image]

If you have more than one group, you would probably want to calculate those points separately first. Here, using `dplyr`

```
iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  summarise(min = min(Petal.Length)
            , max = max(Petal.Length)
            , median = median(Petal.Length)
            ) %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_boxplot(
    aes(x = Species
        , lower = min
        , middle = median
        , upper = max
        , ymin = min
        , ymax = max)
    , stat = "identity"
  )
```

[image]

If you want to add a "legend" you may need to do a bit more adjustment. However, with `cowplot` it is relatively easy to simply create a plot labelled in the way you would like and then use it as the legend. Below, I create the same boxplot as above (but save it to a variable) and create a new plot to serve as the legend (modify as needed).

```
basePlot <-
  iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  summarise(min = min(Petal.Length)
            , max = max(Petal.Length)
            , median = median(Petal.Length)
  ) %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_boxplot(
    aes(x = Species
        , lower = min
        , middle = median
        , upper = max
        , ymin = min
        , ymax = max)
    , stat = "identity"
  )


legendPlot <-
  data.frame(lower = 1, middle = 2, upper = 3) %>%
  ggplot(
    aes(x = 1
        , lower = lower
        , middle = middle
        , upper = upper
        , ymin = lower
        , ymax = middle
    )
  ) +
  # ggtitle("Legend") +
  geom_boxplot(stat = "identity") +
  scale_y_continuous(
    name = ""
    , breaks = 1:3
    , labels = c("Minimum", "Median", "Maximum")
  ) +
  scale_x_continuous("Legend", position = "top") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank()
        , axis.title.x = element_text(face = "bold"))
```

Then, load `cowplot` (note that I am resetting the theme because `cowplot` autoloads its own theme and I don't care for it) and create the layout using `plot_grid`. Note that here I am creating two separate columns in order to make the legend smaller and vertically centered. You can play with `rel_widths` and `rel_heights` if you want to adjust the details. (`scale` is an option too, but I didn't like how it worked with `rel_widths`.)

```
library(cowplot)
theme_set(theme_minimal())


plot_grid(
  basePlot
  , plot_grid(
    ggplot()
    , legendPlot
    , ggplot()
    , ncol = 1
  )
  , rel_widths = c(1, 0.33)
)
```

Gives

[image]

Comment: Is there another way to calculate the values in advance than doing it with dplyr and %>% ? Doesn't seem to work for me...

Comment: Probably. That is likely a separate question, but `by` would likely get you started. What do you mean "Doesn't seem to work"?

Comment: This works fine. Is there a way to print a customized box into the margins and add some annotations at the min/median/max. Since it is a customized box I would like to add some infotmation to make it understandable for other People.

Comment: See edit. Also, if this works and answers your question, it is generally appropriate to accept the answer.

Comment: Hey Mark. For some reason R Returns the following error when I execute the cowplot part of your code: Error in x - from[1] : non-numeric argument to binary Operator. Do you have an idea?

Comment: Hey Mark. the error occured because I was using outdated versions of some packages.